# An error in creating a method for work with PostgreSQL

Tags: java, eclipse

I really can't understand what's going wrong. I connected the PostgreSQL to Eclipse - it works, created a method for creating a table - works. But I can't create a method for inserting data into the table. Eclipse gives me an error(exactly in the method' announcement). 
The screenshot and code are below.

```
private static void insertDBUserTable(int id, String name, String login, String password) { 
    Connection dbConnection1 = null;
    Statement statement1 = null;

    String insertTableSQL = "INSERT  INTO users VALUES (" 
                            + "'" + id + "'" + ", "
                            + "'" + name + "'" + ", "
                            + "'" + login + "'" + ", "
                            + "'" + password + "'"
                            + ");";

    try {
        dbConnection1 = getDBConnection();
        statement1 = dbConnection.createStatement();
        statement1.executeUpdate(insertTableSQL);
        System.out.println("Користувача додано");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (statement1 != null) {
            statement1.close();
        }
        if (dbConnection1 != null) {
            dbConnection1.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image: Screenshot]

Will be grateful for help.

Comment: this is just rife with sql injection attacks, this is not the correct way to build sql statements in any language!

Comment: I'm just learning. It's my first project with sql statements in Java... 
So, which is the right way?

Comment: do you not see the duplicate link at the top of the question in the big yellow box now?